# i forgot the SQL 2005 tool that helps me extract the database into scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I forgot the name of that application tool. anyone here remembers it?

It let's me log-in to my remote SQL database and I can create scripts of the schema and procedures and even data.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: no not management studio... its a smaller app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do this with [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) 2005/2008.

To script database schema - right click the specific database in the Object Explorer, select Tasks->Generate Scripts and follow the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools. http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
Its open source, and specifically designed to script an entire database - tables, views, procs and data to disk, and then re-create that database through a deployment target.